# WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and WM_SYSKEYDOWN

Tags: winapi

```
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
```

If I add the line above, my program will only receive every second press of an Alt key. I catch the Alt key with the WM_SYSKEYDOWN event. I must mention though, that WM_SYSKEY**UP** still detects every release of an Alt key.

So when I just repeatedly press the alt key the log looks like this:

DOWN UP UP DOWN UP UP

Any idea why is that, and how to fix the problem but still retain the normal application window look? (That is why overlapped window flag is used).

UPDATE:
I also found that WS_SYSMENU causes the same problem, so it must be something related to sys menu hotkeys.

Comment: Please elaborate on why would you propose to close my question.

Comment: Because you did not provide adequate code to show what you are attempting to do, how you are receiving and processing keystrokes, etc.  In any case, your code is *ERASING EVERY STYLE* the window originally has. To preserve styles, you need to call `GetWindowLong()` first, *add/remove* only the styles you are interested in, and then call `SetWindowLong()` to assign the updated styles.